# Problem with customer custom attributes

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have a problem with my Magento, since I added some customer custom attributes... Here we can see `siret_number`, `function`, `structure_type`.

[image]

Fields are display on the create form customer, but when I want to create the account, I have this error

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text::validateLength() must be of the type string, null given"
```

So, I try to debug the file vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php and on line 80, before the call of the function

```
validateLength(\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $attribute, string $value), for one call the $value is NULL.
```

How to fix this ?

Thanks (I'm a beginner in Magento ;)

Comment: Do you  using 3rd party module for customer?

Comment: No only my custom module

Comment: and this module https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html?edition[]=community) call Clarion_CustomerAttribute